# Center text after an image in the middle of a SpannableString

Tags: android

I am making an app that will require dynamically generated strings, some of which need images in the middle of the string. For example I have one problem that needs an integral symbol from a to b, and ∫ is not good enough. I tried

```
ImageSpan integralOne = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_integral_one);
String s = getString(R.string.problem_type_three);
s = s+"5";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
ss.setSpan(integralOne, 93, 94, 0);
text.setText(ss);
```

but the text after the image is aligned to the bottom of the image. The string contains the question, which has a formula at the end of it.  The 5 represents the dynamically generated content. Is there any way to center text middle to the middle rather than bottom to bottom?

Edit: I tried the suggestion of changing

```
ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_integral_one);
```

to

```
ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_integral_one, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
```

And it pushed the image up higher [Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poPsd.jpg). Is there a different way I should be going about this?

Comment: were you able to come up with any solution? Facing this same issue

Answer (score 0):

align default ALIGN_BOTTOM

try this

```
ImageSpan integral = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_integral_one, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
```